# Curl https xml result returns blank (boolean false) in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

Please need your help!
I send a post using cURL but the response is blank (boolean false). If I post the data on browser like just pressing the `https://www.example.com/myaccount/transfer.php?username=usernamer&password=pass&deposit=5` the browser shows the following result:

> `1 0 success Your account has been deposited`.

When I see the browser source code the results are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TransferResponse>
<version>1</version>
<result>0</result>
<resultstring>success</resultstring>
<description>Your account has been deposited</description>
</TransferResponse>
```

Let me attach the my cURL code:

```
<?php

$config = array
(
"url"        => "https://www.example.com/myaccount/",
"transfer"   => "transfer.php",
"browser"    => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16"
);

$postFields = "username=username&password=pass&deposit=5";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url'] . $config['transfer']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cert/GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['browser']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $config['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($content);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $content;

?>
```

Please, assist me to get the result in cURL. I have tried many ways. I have surfed internet for 2 days straight. At last I decided to ask here. Can someone figure out what the problem is? The followings are done:

- Command line shows the result of `http` *(not https)* as xml.
- Command line returns the result of `https` *(not http)* follows:
      **Failed: Error Number: 60. Reason: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed**
- cURL result of `http` *(not https)* just redirects warning page of www.example.com
- `var_dump($content); and var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` results are:

  boolean false
  array (size=26)
    'url' => string 'https://www.example.com/myaccount/transfer.php' (length=46)
    'content_type' => null
    'http_code' => int 0
    'header_size' => int 0
    'request_size' => int 0
    'filetime' => int -1
    'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
    'redirect_count' => int 0
    'total_time' => float 1.451
    'namelookup_time' => float 0
    'connect_time' => float 0
    'pretransfer_time' => float 0
    'size_upload' => float 0
    'size_download' => float 0
    'speed_download' => float 0
    'speed_upload' => float 0
    'download_content_length' => float -1
    'upload_content_length' => float -1
    'starttransfer_time' => float 0
    'redirect_time' => float 0
    'certinfo' => 
      array (size=0)
        empty
    'primary_ip' => string '177.70.43.10' (length=11)
    'primary_port' => int 443
    'local_ip' => string '192.168.11.9' (length=0)
    'local_port' => int 0
    'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: Can you `echo(curl_error())`?

Comment: This is the cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed. Please help me. Many thanks.

Comment: There's likely a problem with the certificate that the browser can ignore, but curl can't. I'd try to find out in the browser what the problem is - the certificate may have expired, or be invalid for that domain name. Not sure whether curl can be told to ignore certificate problems

Comment: Any suggestions that I can do in this situation to solve the problem? Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: As said,  I'd try to find out in the browser what the problem with the certificate is. The browser may be showing a message somewhere. If that fails, I'd try Googling `php curl ignore certificate` and see whether anything useful comes up

Comment: Pekka, I did everything. I checked the browser and the CA certificate has not expired and valid. I just exported it in pem format and put this in a folder as I refered in the code as you can see. My browsers(Chrome, Firefox, IE) all show the result fine. However curl can't.

Answer (score 1):

If this

> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

is your problem, the [`curl_setopt()` setting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
```

might be for you:

> FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate
>   certificates to verify against can be specified with the
>   CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with
>   the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.

So set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and probably also

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: I tried both combinations. If I set them false the site refers to `www.example.com/warning.html` page. string 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 20:03:35 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://www.example.com/warning.html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: This worked fine for me. This was on a local dev host, which probably didn't have CA's installed, so this is a quick fix that works, but not something for a production environment.

Comment: This worked for me: `code`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`/code`

Answer (score 1):

Setting SSL verification to false defeats the purpose of SSL.
A proper solution is to set the CA certs for CURL.

Solution 1 (Changes to PHP.ini):

1. Download CA bundle (cacert.pem) from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place it on your local system (for eg: C:\xampp\cacert.pem)
3. Open your php.ini
4. Set the curl.ca_info options to point to the location of the cacert.pem

   ```
   Example: curl.ca_info="C:\xampp\cacert.pem"
   ```
5. Restart Apache

Solution 2 (Set options before each CURL call)

1. Download CA bundle (cacert.pem) from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place it on your local system (for eg: C:\xampp\cacert.pem)
3. Write the following code:

   ```
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "pathto\cacert.pem");
   ```

Source: http://tumblr.wehavefaces.net/post/52114563111/environment-windows-xampp-curl-library

Comment: What do you do when this doesn't seem to make a difference, calling the same curl request in one part of the code gives valid http_code, calling from another file gives http_code 0?